# How do I create a Solr query that returns results even if one field in my query has no matches?

Tags: solr, lucene

Suppose I want to create a recommendation system to suggest people you should connect with based off of certain attributes that I know about you and attributes I have about other people that are stored in a Solr index. Is it possible to query the index with a list of attributes (along with boosts for each attribute) and have Solr return scored results *even if* some of my fields return no matches? The way that I understand that Solr works is that if one of your fields doesn't contain a match in any documents found in your index, you get zero results for the entire query (even if other fields in the query matched) - is that right? What I would hope is that I could query the index and get a list of results back in order of a score given based on how many (and which) fields matched to something, even if some fields have no matches, for example:

Say that there are 2 people documents stored in the index as follows (figuratively):

```
Person 1:
     Industry: Manufacturing
     City: Oakland

Person 2:
     Industry: Manufacturing 
     City: San Jose
```

And say that I perform a pseudo-Solr query that basically says "Search for everyone whose industry is equal to manufacturing and whose city is equal to Oakland". What I would like is to receive both results back in the result set, even though one of the "Persons" does not reside in Oakland. I just want that person to come back as a result with a lower score than Person1. Is this possible? What might a solr query look like to handle this? Assume that I have many more than 2 attributes for each person (so saying that I can use "And" and "Or" in my solr query isn't really feasible.. or is it?) Thanks in advance for your helpful input! (PS I'm using Solr 3.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention using the `AND` operator, which is likely your problem.

The default behavior of Lucene, and Solr, query syntax is exactly what you are asking for.  A query like:

```
industry:manufacturing city:oakland
```

Will match either, with scoring preference on those that match both.  See [the lucene query syntax documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Overview)

Comment: Is it possible to add boosts to the fields (using the default behavior of lucene)?

Comment: @user1431072 Yes.  Did you read the [syntax documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Boosting_a_Term)?  It's right there.  Like `field1:important^5 field2:stuff`

Comment: http://localhost:8983/solr/persons/select/?q={!lucene}Industry:Manufacturing^10 City:Oakland^5 doesn't seem to work at all. I assume it has something to do with the space between the search fields in the query. Since I'm not supposed to use "And" or "Or", what should go in between the two fields in the query? I've  looked at the lucene query syntax page as you've suggested and can't find out how...

Comment: Query looks all right to me, a space should be fine.  Is the space being [URL encoded](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax#NOTE:_URL_Escaping_Special_Characters)?

Comment: Ah-hah. You're right, the query is good, I just need to pay attention to case-sensitivity for field names and values.

Comment: Do you know if using "+" between the search fields is acceptable? The reason I ask is because I'm using a c# library (SolrNet) to assist in creating my Solr Queries. I notice that when I create a query with multiple fields, it adds a plus sign ("+") between each field like so: City:Denver^10+Industry:Manufacturing^15. I seem to be getting the same number of results back, but would like to know if the use of the plus sign is affecting my results under-the-hood...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bq parameter (boost query) does not affect matching, but affects the scores only.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/persons/select?q=industry:manufacturing&bq=City:Oakland^2
```

play with the boosting factor at the end to get the correct balance between matching score, and boosting score.

Comment: Would using the "bq" (boost query) work on all fields? Or does there need to be a minimum number of matching fields as well (in a single query, that is)?

Comment: it just changes the boosting scores for returned documents, so it just affect the order of results. the query could be empty query (*:*) or could be any number of fields, they work separately